# C# WPF binding DataGrid on SelectedItem from another DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have two DataGrid elements. The first one is loaded with article data and the second one should display further data based on the SelectedItem of the first DataGrid.

The binding of the first DataGrid with the article data works perfectly.

Now I have a second one, which should display more data depending on the selection of the first one. In the ViewModel.cs I have created the following:

```
    public BindableCollection<ArticleDataModel> ArticleDataList {
        get; set;
    }

    public BindableCollection<QuantityModel> WarehouseQuantityList {
        get; set;
    }


    private ArticleDataModel currentSelection;

    public ArticleDataModel CurrentSelection {
        get {
            return currentSelection;
        }
        set {
            currentSelection = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => currentSelection);
            this.LoadQuantity();
        }
    }
```

The first DatagridView is bound to **ArticleDataList**, all data is displayed correctly. When selecting a dataset I can see in the debugger that the method LoadQuantity() is called and that WarehouseQuantityList contains all data.

However, the data is not displayed to me, not even record rows are displayed.

The binding in XAML looks like this:

```
<!-- Artikel ListView -->
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="ArticleDataList"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AlternatingRowBackground="#fafafa"
    FontSize="14"
    RowBackground="#eee"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#ddd"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="#ddd"
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelection}">
```

and

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WarehouseQuantityList"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AlternatingRowBackground="#fafafa"
    FontSize="14"
    RowBackground="#eee"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#ddd"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="#ddd"
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow">
```

Binding is both times over **x:Name**, the items are bound like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Lagerplatz" Width="250" Binding="{Binding Path=Lagerplatz}"/>
```

The binding is technically the same for both, but I don't get any errors or exceptions. The loaded data is correct and also available in WarehouseQuantityList. Only the DataGrid does not see them. So I assume that I'm making a mistake, just don't know where?

I am always open for hints :-)

Comment: Where did you set ItemsSource for both the DataGrids?

Comment: How do you set the `WarehouseQuantityList` property and the `ItemsSource` of the second `DataGrid`? How is  `LoadQuantity ` implemented? `LoadQuantity` should set `WarehouseQuantityList` and also raise a `PropertyChanged` event to tell the view to reload the `DataGrid`. Then it should work provided that you actually bound to `WarehouseQuantityList`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, my mistake was actually that I didn't set NotifyOfPropertyChange for WarehouseQuantityList. Works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Post your answer and mark it as answered